How to determine whether two recursive data types overlap
I am working on a type system that supports recursive data types, e.g.:
type a = (a * integer) | integer
type b = integer

would be valid type declarations, where integer is a base type, * denotes a tuple and | denotes an untagged union type.
To add support for type classes in this system, I need to be able to determine whether two types overlap, as it would otherwise be ambiguous which type class to choose (that is, any integer satisfies type a and b).
For non-recursive data types, checking whether they overlap is quite simple. However, I am unable to come up with an algorithm to do the same for recursive data types. Could such an algorithm exist, or must a solution be approximated?
A possible approach to approximate this problem would be to expand the recursive types to a finite depth, and then comparing them for overlap normally (i.e. as if they were non-recursive). Any remaining type variables should be treated as equal, as their exact contents cannot be determined statically.

I wouldn't call untagged unions "algebraic data types". Does integer + integer mean the same as integer in your system? If so, this is different from a sum type in the usual sense.

@NaïmFavier Yes, it means the same. I have updated my question to clarify this.


Generate a recursive type definition for a fresh type type a∩b that is equivalent to the intersection of type a and type b.

Decide whether the type a∩b is empty. (Doable by fixed point iteration.)


Step 1 in more detail: given two type definitions type a = A and type b = B (where A and B are expressions consisting of integer (and other base types), * and |), create a definition type a∩b = A ∩ B where a∩b is a fresh type name, and A ∩ B is obtained from the following rewrite rules:
(A1 | A2) ∩ B          ->  (A1 ∩ B) | (A2 ∩ B)
A ∩ (B1 | B2)          ->  (A ∩ B1) | (A ∩ B2)
(A1 * A2) ∩ (B1 * B2)  ->  (A1 ∩ B1) * (A2 ∩ B2)
integer ∩ (B1 * B2)    ->  empty
(A1 * A2) ∩ integer    ->  empty
integer ∩ integer      ->  integer
A ∩ B                  ->  A∩B        if at least one of A or B is a type identifier
; A∩B is a fresh name associated with A and B

Every time you use the last rule, recursively generate a definition for A∩B using those same rules if it doesn't already exist. Only finitely many new definitions will be required.

Another abstract answer is that types can be read as finite tree automata (finite state machines that recognize trees). Chapter 1 of the textbook Tree Automata, Techniques and Applications contains the relevant results, notably: tree automata are closed under intersection (page 24) and emptiness is decidable (page 33). The above algorithm can be viewed as a simplified application of those results.
